# why is the output wrong from what i calculate on paper based on my code?

Tags: c

I've written this code for a class project:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n = 0, i = 1, c = 0, d = 0, a = 0, b = 0, j = 1;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (i <= n)
    {
        b = a;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if (a >= b)
        {   
            i++;
        }
        if (a == b)
        {
            j++;
        }   
        if (a < b)
        {
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
    while ((i <= n) && (i != j + 2))    
    {
        b = a;
        scanf("\n%d", &a);
        if (a < b)
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (a > b || a == b)
        {
            i++;    
            c = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (c == 1)
    {
        while (i <= n)
        {
            scanf("\n%d", &a);
            i++;
        }
        printf("No");
    }        
    while (i <= n)
    {
        b = a;
        scanf("\n%d", &a);
        if (a <= b)
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (a > b);
        {
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (i <= n)
    {
        b = a;
        scanf("\n%d", &a);
        if (a > b)
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (a < b || a == b)
        { 
            i++;
            d = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (d == 1)
    {
        while (i <= n)
        {
            scanf("\n%d", &a);
            i++;
        }
        printf("No");
    }
    if (c != 1 && d != 1)
    {
        printf("Yes");
    }
}
```

and I expect the output for this income:
6
4 4 3 2 3 2

to be "No". But instead, it's "Yes". I go through all of the steps in my code on paper, and the answer i get on my own is correct. But when i run the program it's not. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Use a debugger. Use print statements. Do debugging 101 to trace the execution of the program. We have no idea what the correct output is supposed to be as we don't know what the program is supposed to do. The program could have a bug, your paper calculation could be wrong or both. It's impossible for us to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an error in your code, the semicolon is ending the instruction

```
while (i <= n)
{
    b = a;
    scanf("\n%d", &a);
    if (a <= b)
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (a > b); // remove this semicolon
    {
        i++;
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Just for clarity, is ending the "if" instruction, it's like an empty "if" like:**

```
if ( a > b ) { }
```

so the

```
i++;
break;
```

get executed as the next instructions